# VirtualBox eats up disk memory

Tags: virtualbox

Installed VirtualBox, created the main OS on it, about 50 clones were created from it.

Every time I use them, the disk space where all the clones are stored increases, thereby eating up my hdd.

Is it possible how to delete unnecessary old logs correctly?

Clones are needed to store information, so that when ON and OFF, this data is stored on a virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks for posting your question! Your original question was not in English — the primary language of this website — so I have edited it to translate it from the original Russian (I believe) so it can be read by others here.